# How to install and setup Testswarm?

Tags: debugging, configuration, continuous-integration, qunit, testswarm

![enter image description here][1]Testswarm is a Continuous Integration Testing Framework.

Can anybody tell me how to install and use it?

I have checked the read me on github and installed Testswarm, but I am unable to add jobs or run them.

I added one project by inserting details in database.

I have downloaded qUnit, so please tell me how to write tests in it for Testswarm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add project and create jobs in TestSwarm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730478/how-to-add-project-and-create-jobs-in-testswarm)

Answer (score 0):

The process depends on your environment. Here are some options:

- [TestSwarm Prerequisites](https://github.com/jquery/testswarm/wiki/Automated-Distributed-Continuous-Integration-for-JavaScript)
- [Setting up TestSwarm](https://dseifried.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/setting-up-test-swarm/)
- [TestSwarm: Setting Up Jobs/Tests](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/testswarm-setting-up-jobs-tests)
- [Running tests with TestSwarm](http://jstest.jcoglan.com/testswarm.html)
- [TestSwarm Video Walkthru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkWkY0m-9m0)
- [Automating Cross-Browser Testing](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2011/07/20/refactoring-towards-testable-javascript-part-3/)
- [Continuous Integration Workflow](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/File:Wikimedia_CI_workflow.svg)
- [Integrating TestSwarm with Jenkins](https://github.com/appendto/jenkins-testswarm)
- [Using Jenkins + TestSwarm + QUnit for JavaScript Tests on a Windows Environment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xusun/archive/2011/10/24/using-jenkins-testswarm-qunit-for-javascript-test-on-windows-environment.aspx)
- [TestSwarm Notes: Installing TestSwarm](http://wiki.collectionspace.org/display/collectionspace/Step+1+-+Notes+for+Installing+TestSwarm)
- [TestSwarn Notes: Adding a User; Adding Basic Jobs](http://wiki.collectionspace.org/display/collectionspace/Step+2+-+TestSwarm+Notes+Adding+User%2C+Adding+Basic+Jobs)