# How to add project and create jobs in TestSwarm

Tags: jquery, qunit, testswarm

I am trying setting up TestSwarm, but not able to create project and jobs.
When cloning TestSwarm from github some files are missing like /run etc.

Please suggest your thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

You create a project using

```
php scripts/manageProject.php --create=true --id="yourtestid" --display-title="your display title here"
```

This script creates a project and requires an id and a display title, and also has optional options for site-url and password.  The create flag tells the script to create the project if it doesn't already exist.

The script will return an auth token (which can be re-created with scripts/refreshProjectToken.php).

Comment: wasn't running previously but ran after adding --password="my_password"